# AlertDialog из GCMIntentService

Tags: android

Можно ли в GCMIntentService вместо отправления пуша в панель нотификации, отображать информацию в AlertDialog? При условви конечно, что приложение открыто. Как проверить, что приложение открыто я знаю. Не знаю, какой конетекс передавать AlertDialog'у

Comment: Если это возможно, то по кнопке "ОК" AlertDialog'a в приложении должна начаться определённая активность. Насколько это всё можно реализовать? Какова сложность этой задачи?

Comment: если знаете, что приложение открыто, то и открывайте в нем диалог, а не в сервисе. В activity повесьте receiver например